# Called object type 'std::function<void (T1 *, T2 *)> *' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++

I have this weird bug in my code where I'm trying to call a callback but the compiler doesn't think that `std::function` is a function?

Here is the error and relevant code snippets below (Some functions and structs have been renamed for readability)

```
misc/event.inl:59:13: error: called object type 'std::function<void (T1 *, T2 *)> *' is not a function or function pointer
            (*callback).func(args...);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The function and array themselves are stored within a class

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
struct callback
{
    std::function<void(Args... args)> *func;
    bool destructive;
}

// this->callbacks is of type std::vector<std::shared_ptr<callback>>
template <typename... Args>
bool callbackHandler<Args...>::trigger(Args... args)
{
    for (auto &callback : *(this->callbacks))
    {
        printf("%i", callback->destructive);
        (*callback).func(args...);
        if (callback->destructive)
        {
            this->remove(callback);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is this an error with the compiler or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: *Is this an error with the compiler* - [First Rule of Programming](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) says otherwise. `func` is **a pointer to `std::function`**, you have to dereference that (or stop using pointers in the first place).

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to `std::function`? Why not `std::function` directly?

Comment: And you seem to be using way to many pointers. You almost *never* need a pointer to a container (like `std::vector`), for example. And there's really no need for a pointer to a `std::function` for that matter.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude I reduced the amount of pointers I was using and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> doesn't think that `std::function` is a function?

That's because it isn't. It's a class which has an `operator()`, which allows it to be used like a function.

The local fix is to dereference `func` where you are calling it, i.e.

```
(*callback->func)(args...);
```

But the simpler thing is to not use pointers.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct callback
{
    std::function<void(Args... args)> func;
    bool destructive;
};

// this->callbacks is of type std::vector<callback>
```

N.b. `this->remove(callback);` sounds like it causes undefined behaviour, if it removes from `this->callbacks` while you are iterating over it.